# Edit Script To Make Character Move In Direction He Is Facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the Third Person Controller asset by Opsive.  It is a fairly complex third person controller that controls animations, damage, movement, inputs, etc etc.
http://opsive.com/assets/ThirdPersonController/documentation.php

I would like to update the ControllerHandler.cs script to make the character move in the direction that the character is facing, regardless of camera orientation.  (In the style of old Resident Evil games)

In the original script, the character would move forward in relation to which direction the camera was facing.

I received some advice to change a line in this script, but with the changes, the character moves forward in one fixed direction.  (E.G.:  When I turn to the right with the D key, and then press W to move forward, the character turns back in the direction he was originally facing and moves in that direction.)

Here is the original part of the script:

```
#if ENABLE_MULTIPLAYER
            if ( isLocalPlayer) {
#endif
            if (m_Controller.Movement == RigidbodyCharacterController.MovementType.Combat || m_Controller.Movement == RigidbodyCharacterController.MovementType.Adventure) {
                m_LookRotation = m_CameraTransform.rotation;
```

Here is what someone told me to change it to:

```
#if ENABLE_MULTIPLAYER
            if ( isLocalPlayer) {
#endif
            if (m_Controller.Movement == RigidbodyCharacterController.MovementType.Combat || m_Controller.Movement == RigidbodyCharacterController.MovementType.Adventure) {
                m_LookRotation = Quaternion.Euler(PlayerInput.GetAxisRaw(Constants.YawInputName), 0, 0);
```

Unfortunately, this does not have the result that I intended.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Here is a link to the controller script:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B4sstqtCqRMCLuHuxEuA9I7tO_3W4aHqEZwr73uFDjY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
 transform.position += transform.rotation * Vector3.forward;
```

A complete block of code would look like this...

```
 void Update() {
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
           transform.position += transform.rotation * Vector3.forward * MOVESPEED;
      }
 }
```

Comment: I apologize, but I am fairly new to coding, still heavily in the beginner learning phase.  Where would I insert that code?

Comment: see the updated answer. set your MOVESPEED to something like 0.1

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using the Third Person Controller by Opsive from the Unity Asset Store.  Here is a link to the controller script: 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B4sstqtCqRMCLuHuxEuA9I7tO_3W4aHqEZwr73uFDjY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working. Take a look at the picture first it will help you set up the player correctly. My player is just two cubes. I added the second cube to give a face to where the player is pointing. I have added those 2 cube to a parent object and I move the parent object with my `PlayerMovement.cs`. [image]

```
public float rotSpeed;
public float playerSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate( Vector3.up,  Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(-Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);
        } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain the situation well enough in the OP.  I am using a full Third Person Controller kit from Opsive, purchased on the Asset Store.  It is fairly complex and controls animations, interactions, abilities such as ledge walking, climbing and swimming, damage, inventory, movement, inputs, basically everything.  I edited the original post to include the ControllerHandler.cs script via google docs.  What I need to do is update the included script to get the desired results without breaking anything.

Thanks for the reply, though.  Any help is greatly appreciated.